# Angularjs page cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I am new to angularjs, and I want to know is there some thing like page caching in angularjs,
(considering the page caching is different from Angularjs $cacheFactor) 
Because I know come across this link, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06bh14hk(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06bh14hk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  which looks pretty good concept.

Can anybody give me the same concept that can be acheived in angularjs, OR relatively similar to page caching.

Comment: I don't think there is anything precisely similar because you're doing very different things. Asp.NET is caching pages/HTTP responses server side, while angularJS runs entirely client side. Maybe you're looking for something like $templateCache? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: There is the $templateCache that will cache the requested templates. $http will cache the request depending on the server caching headers.  It you are worried about speed you can look at the 'track by' feature for ng-repeats.